# why json values converted to string in my code

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a few values that I want give from Json

what I received from server:

(as you can see values aren't string)

```
 "HP": {
  "BaseValue": 44.0, //float
   "Point": 3.0, //float
   "UpdateFactor": 1.5 //float
   }
```

After receiving jason from server

```
IEnumerator ReceiveJson()
{
    var postScoreURL = Url;
    var postHeader = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    WWW request = new WWW(postScoreURL, null, postHeader);
    yield return request;
    if (request.error != null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Receive = JSONNode.Parse(request.text);
        Debug.Log(Receive);
    }
}
```

why I received string value?
(but here I have string values!!!)

```
 "HP": {
  "BaseValue": "44.0", //string
   "Point": "3.0", //string
   "UpdateFactor": "1.5" //string
   }
```

Comment: Did you try using `.AsFloat` ?

Comment: @MarkC. yeah I used it but I it return 0 !!! I think because it's string it return it

Comment: Is `Receive` a class or some C# representation of JSON?

Comment: @MarkC. `Receive["HP"]["BaseValue"].AsFloat`

Comment: Try `.AsInt`. as a test?

Comment: @MarkC.I need this value of float.

Comment: The point was to see if it would still be a string or not.. hence the words "try" and "test"

Comment: @MarkC. I try Receive["HP"]["BaseValue"].AsInt and return 0!

Comment: Are you tied to this JSON parsing library or can you utilize Newtonsoft or another library?

Comment: I use the SimpleJson library, but tell me if you have a better library

Comment: I would just go with Newtonsoft Json.NET

Comment: use https://app.quicktype.io to create a proper model class and then use Unity's JSONUtility to parse it

Answer (score -3):

Your json is invalid. 
You can check your json at [Jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Your json needs to look like this:

```
{
    "HP": {
        "BaseValue": 44.0,
        "Point": 3.0,
        "UpdateFactor": 1.5
    }
}
```

Comment: what part of my jason is invalid?

Comment: That is simply not true. Floating point numbers are perfectly valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, floats are perfectly valid, but the JSON is still invalid (it needs to be surrounded with `{...}`

Comment: Floats are perfectly valid, not sure from what spec you got that from.

Comment: Even the link you posted will validate floats successfully.

Comment: OK. I'm wrong, sorry. I've edited my answer. Thanks for the down votes, I deserved them.

Comment: OK, now you have edited, can you say that the floats won't be enclosed inside quotes any more?